# How can I diplay the title of the article on Facebook wall with wordpress and share.php

Tags: facebook, wordpress

My Environment

- PHP 5.3.2
- WordPress 3.4.1

I an managing a wordpress site and I want to share a post link in the facebook.
There are some article in one page (index.php).

then I use the following link for diplay the title of each posts.

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
(snip)
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="_blank">share</a>
(snip)
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

However I click the link and the share title and link are the wordpress itsself (not article's ones).
Is it the problem of facebook cache? and How Can I solve it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: at the very least, you should upgrade your PHP to the latest version of 5.3 -- there have been numerous important bug fixes since 5.3.2. current version is 5.3.15, which should give you an idea of how far behind you are. (there's also 5.4 available now, which you may want to consider too, but upgrading 5.3 is important; moving to 5.4 is just a luxury)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put [open graph meta tags](http://ogp.me/) on each page of your site for Facebook to properly show titles, etc. Wordpress does not include these by default. Take a look at several of your page in the Facebook debugger, and you'll probably see a bunch of errors because of missing tags.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

There are several plugins that will do this for you. I personally like [Yoast's Wordpress SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/). The official [Facebook plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/) also does this, but still has several bugs to be worked out. There are dozens more if you don't like either of these two.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I used the og:title and og:url etc.. but in the top page which has several posts, the og:title has high priority than the title of the share query.

I want to use different title for each articles.

Anyway I try to use plugins you recommend.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In you header.php file add this line somewhere before the closing `</head>` tag

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php wp_title(); ?>"/>
```

This will structure the title that shows up in Facebook like - Cool Blog Name - Awesome Post Title

Also Facebook may cache the values for a link that has already been shared.  If you input the url here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug you will see the values Facebook will try and use so it is good for testing and should clear the cached values.